# Remove duplicate excel-rows when 2 columns have to match

Tags: excel, duplicates

I'm trying to find duplicates in Excel where Name and Currency is equal.

ID | Currency | Product

1  | EUR      | Product 1

2  | EUR      | Product 1

3  | GBP      | Product 1

4  | GBP      | Product 1

5  | USD      | Product 1

6  | USD      | Product 1

I would like to just have on of those rows in the file:

ID | Currency | Product

1  | EUR      | Product 1

3  | GBP      | Product 1

5  | USD      | Product 1

Comment: What have you tried / researched so far, and what specific problem are you having?

Answer (score 0):

Use DATA>Remove Duplicates and select columns Currency and Product.

[See example here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/find-and-remove-duplicates-00e35bea-b46a-4d5d-b28e-66a552dc138d)